# Configuring Network in Chapter 2 : basic environment of Openstack installation guide

Tags: networking, openstack, centos7

I am currently following the kilo openstack installation guide for redhat linux flavors. I am kind of stuck on the Configuring Network step in Chapter 2: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/yum/content/ch_basic_environment.html#

The guide tells me to :

```
Configure the first interface as the management interface:

IP address: 10.0.0.31

Network mask: 255.255.255.0 (or /24)

Default gateway: 10.0.0.1
```

However, it doesn't show how to do so. How would this work in centos?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They guide is simply referring to standard CentOS network interface configuration, it is not something that is specific to OpenStack.

Assuming your host has two network interfaces, you should be able to see the interface names by running the command

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Here is some sample output (my management interface already has the IP address configured so it is showing up as the interface with IP 10.0.2.31):

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feae:d2fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:ae:d2:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2408605  bytes 1525820305 (1.4 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 95427  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 210  bytes 22059 (21.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe3c:a34e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:3c:a3:4e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 561650  bytes 195828420 (186.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 636197  bytes 242737796 (231.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is important for you is the name of your interfaces, in the sample output above you can see there are two interfaces: **enp0s3** and **enp0s8**

Pick the one you want to use as the management interface and configure it with a static IP address.  Using the example interfaces from above, where we are using interface enp0s8, you would need to edit the file **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8** and set the IP address and other information.

Here is a sample of the contents for that file, replace IP addresses for the ones that are applicable to your setup:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTn="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s8"
DEVICE="enp0s8"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=10.0.2.31
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=10.0.2.2
DNS1=8.8.8.8
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

For more detailed information on configuring your interface with a static IP on CentOS 7 see http://www.usecentos.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=14&id=1073

Comment: Does configuring only work for the interfaces present in ifconfig? I want to configure this without touching the interfaces in my ifconfig.

Comment: You don't have to change the IP addresses of your existing interfaces to use OpenStack, just adapt the OpenStack configuration.  So in this example, if you already have an interface eth0 with IP 192.168.1.101, just use that IP address instead of 10.0.0.31 when following the OpenStack setup steps. Alternatively you can use IP aliasing to add a second IP to your interface, e.g. if you have eth0 with an IP address, you can do "ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.31".  Note that this will need to be in the same subnet as the existing IP address on that interface.

Comment: So if they already exist, Instead of following the configure network step, I can just follow the configure name resolution step?
When I  Edit the /etc/hosts file to contain the following: 
# controller 10.0.0.11       controller
# network 10.0.0.21       network
# compute1 10.0.0.31       compute1
Since I have existing ip addresses, I can just replace the ones in there with mine right? 

Also, how come I only see 2 interfaces when I go into the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ directory? Two of the interfaces in ifconfig are not present in this directory.

Comment: That is correct, the IP addresses in the guide are just examples, you can use whatever IP address you want and then just make sure you substitute the IP addresses used in the rest of the steps with your actual IP addresses.  If there are no files for the interfaces you want to modify in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ you can just add them yourself.   I would recommend spending time becoming very familiar with CentOS networking before continuing with the rest of the OpenStack setup.

Comment: If all three of my interfaces belong to one node, would I still be able to adapt one of the interfaces as my controller and alias the other 2 as network/compute? Or do they need to be individual nodes themselves? I'm reading more about CentOS networking right now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: It's not that you need one interface per node, you need one interface per network on each node as illustrated in the guide. If you want to set everything up on a single node I would suggest you look into "devstack", it is a much simpler option for getting started and learning openstack.